# Woocommerce custom shortcode returns zero value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom *Thank you* page in wordpress which has this paragraph:

> Thank you so much for your order!
>
> After paying off `[cart_total]` via XYZ website, please fill out
>   this form and inform us about your payment.

And tried this custom shortcode:

```
// Total Price Shortcode 

function cart_wctotal(){

   global $woocommerce;
   $wctotal = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();

   return "<span class='cart-total'> ".$wctotal."</span>";

}

add_shortcode( 'cart_total', 'cart_wctotal' );
```

But when I check out orders the output returns *zero value* for *Total Price* :

> Thank you so much for your order!
>
> After paying €0.00 via XYZ website, please fill out this form and
>   inform us about your payment.

Comment: You mention a "Thank You" page that says "Thank you for your order" - wouldn't that mean the cart is now empty ("purchase" completed?), and you'll instead need to get the most recent [$order](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) total with `WC_Order->get_total()`?

Comment: @Xhynk , You are right! Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comment from @[xhynk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/933810/xhynk) why your code is not going to work.

Get last order (and order total) by user id

```php
function cart_wctotal(){
    // Get user id
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get last order by user id
    $last_order = wc_get_customer_last_order( $user_id );

    // Order total
    $wctotal = $last_order->get_total();

    return "<span class='cart-total'> " . $wctotal . "</span>";
}
add_shortcode( 'cart_total', 'cart_wctotal' );
```

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r ! It seems `get_total` doesn't have currency symbol, So I made a minor modification.

Comment: `function cart_wctotal(){
    // Get user id
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get last order by user id
    $last_order = wc_get_customer_last_order( $user_id );

    // Order total
    $wctotal = $last_order->get_total();
    
    //Currency
    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); 
    
    $wctotals = $currency."".$wctotal." ";

    return "<span class='cart-total'> " . $wctotals . "</span>";
}

add_shortcode( 'cart_total', 'cart_wctotal' );`